# Is there a way to produce a scatterplot using ggplot2 from a tibble with all the values in a single columns without pivot_wider?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have a dataframe with three columns:

```
sampleData <- structure(list(sgRNA = c("SFPQ_9", "SFPQ_9", "FBXO18_13", "FBXO18_13", 
                         "DDX21_55", "DDX21_55", "TAF6L_11", "TAF6L_11", "NAA40_3", "NAA40_3", 
                         "KDM5A_1", "KDM5A_1", "DGKH_17", "DGKH_17", "NAA30_15", "NAA30_15", 
                         "HMG20A_8", "HMG20A_8", "CASKIN1_35", "CASKIN1_35", "NUBP1_20", 
                         "NUBP1_20", "CTCF_9", "CTCF_9", "THAP11_17", "THAP11_17", "EZH1_9", 
                         "EZH1_9", "SMARCD2_21", "SMARCD2_21", "E2F6_6", "E2F6_6", "CENPA_11", 
                         "CENPA_11", "SP140_35", "SP140_35", "SETD4_3", "SETD4_3", "STAG3_9", 
                         "STAG3_9", "RAD54B_39", "RAD54B_39", "SMC1A_59", "SMC1A_59", 
                         "ZNF257_1246", "ZNF257_1246", "DYNC1I2_4", "DYNC1I2_4", "NTC_77", 
                         "NTC_77"), replicate = c("R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", 
                                                  "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", 
                                                  "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", 
                                                  "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", 
                                                  "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2", "R1", "R2"
                         ), abundance = c(450L, 583L, 209L, 231L, 212L, 288L, 958L, 1103L, 
                                          562L, 717L, 388L, 452L, 290L, 330L, 201L, 281L, 142L, 258L, 608L, 
                                          850L, 218L, 328L, 522L, 711L, 623L, 772L, 371L, 471L, 56L, 52L, 
                                          160L, 135L, 359L, 416L, 213L, 348L, 301L, 416L, 185L, 256L, 222L, 
                                          238L, 347L, 536L, 765L, 973L, 115L, 117L, 102L, 132L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to build a scatterplot. All the values are in the "abundance" column and the "replicate" specifies whether the observation is to be used as a coordinate along x or y axis. While "sgRNA" specifies the point. I understand I can pivot the data to wider format to generate two new columns "R1" and "R2" and plot them against each other using ggplot2, but is there a way to do this without pivoting?

Comment: Why you don't want to pivot?

Comment: its not that I dont want to, I just wanted to understand what is the best practice in this case. I dont want to write extra code, however small, if this is unnecessary. Basically I wanted to understand whether it is necessary or I am mssing smth about ggplot2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @www's comment. It's not clear *why* you don't want to pivot.

In response to your question: No, you will need to reshape the data in one way or another.

If you don't like `pivot_wider` you could use `xtabs` with `as.data.frame.matrix` in the following way:

```
ggplot(as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(abundance ~ ., data = sampleData)), aes(R1, R2)) + 
    geom_point()
```

[image]

But this is still a reshape from long to wide.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I don't think it's about writing extra code, but more about reproducibility and understanding what was done, for yourself some time the road, or for someone else trying to understand what you did.

This below works, but hey not the most intuitive:

```
ggplot(data.frame(split(sampleData$abundance,sampleData$replicate)),
aes(x=R1,y=R2)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess in some rare cases, such as you are using a company's computer, which you cannot have access to `tidyr`, then the following may work, which only uses `dplyr` and `ggplot2`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

R1 <- sampleData %>% filter(replicate %in% "R1") %>% select(-replicate) 
R2 <- sampleData %>% filter(replicate %in% "R2") %>% select(-replicate)
R1R2 <- R1 %>% left_join(R2, by = "sgRNA", suffix = c("_R1", "_R2"))

ggplot(R1R2, aes(x = abundance_R1, y = abundance_R2)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These do not use tidyr but do convert the data to wide form using other methods:

**1)** Read `sampleData` into a zoo object splitting on the second column, convert that to a data frame (which will have columns `R1` and `R2`) and use `qplot` from ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(zoo)

sampleData %>%
  read.zoo(split = 2, FUN = c) %>%
  as.data.frame %$%
  qplot(R1, R2)
```

[image: screenshot]

**2)** Another approach giving the same result is to use `tapply`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

sampleData %$%
  tapply(.[[3]], .[-3], c) %>%
  as.data.frame.matrix %$% 
  qplot(R1, R2)
```

This could also be written without magrittr like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

with(as.data.frame.matrix(tapply(sampleData[[3]], sampleData[-3], c)),
  qplot(R1, R2))
```